# Rails routing all subdomains with wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing site with the pattern:

`CappedIn.com/users/1`

I would like my users to also be accessible via

`MyUsername.CappedIn.com`

I would like to be able to catch all subdomains and then perform a quick lookup in a controller and render a user profile. The rendered URL would be of course `MyUsername.CappedIn.com`

Is this possible? How can it be achieved?

Note that I am currently on Rails 3.2 but will be migrating to Rails 5. So a Rails 5 solution would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look up a `User` model instance from the subdomain of your current URI, you would do something akin to the following (simple, crude example on purpose):

**Look up User via hook in ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  before_action :lookup_user_from_subdomain
  # ...

  def lookup_user_from_subdomain
    @subdomain_user = User.where(username: request.subdomain).first
    # Do stuff with @subdomain_user, and/or handle User not found,
    #  check that subdomain != 'www' if you need to, etc.
  end

  # ...
end
```

**Show Profile from UserController**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def subdomain_profile
    @profile = @subdomain_user.profile if @subdomain_user.present?

    # You may want to check for request.xhr? and handle 
    #  respnding to js/json here, for ajax requests to display
    #  profile in a sidebar or somewhere else besides a profile
    #  page.
    # Or, just simply render the profile of the subdomain-user here.
  end

  # ...
end
```

Note I used `before_action`, which is a newer (Rails ~5) convention, and not `before_filter`.

You can see more information on the `request` object [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object), and more on `ActionController` filters [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

Check out [this Railscast on subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) for more information, and in particular, the http://lvh.me:3000/ domain for testing subdomains in local dev.

If you're planing on doing some heavy duty stuff, like scope available data per subdomain (user), or use different databases per user, or in some way treat the application experience differently for each user, check out the [Acts as Tenant gem](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant). It handles multi tenancy in a Rails application, and has built in support for loading users or accounts via subdomains.

Comment: Thank you. Is there something I need to do to make sure all subdomain hit my Rails app?

Comment: @slindsey3000 its likely that there is, but its probably something that takes places in your DNS or webserver settings.